# Get all nodes of an XML file without knowing the tag names

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to load a url of an xml file into my page then use jQuery or ajax to load the 'text' from the xml into a string.  I do not know the attributes.  I've been trying this so far and it hasn't been working out:

```
$(document).read(function){
                    $.get(infile, function(xml){
                    string = $(xml).text());
                    }
                }); 

                document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = string;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script has many errors. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $.get(infile, function(xml){
                  $("#input").text(xml);
                });
            });
```

Comment: how does the $("#input").text(xml) work?  this script is on another page from my html.  Which is why I thought I needed document.getElementID("input").innerHTML = 'someString';

I put that code in and it throw errors...I saw it had an extra } so I pull that and it does nothing now.  This is kicking my butt...been working on it all day.

Comment: What you mean by 'on another page'?

Comment: sorry I meant i am just calling my js file from my html page is all.  sorry for the confusion.  And thank you.

Comment: Well progress sort of.  That is getting return but it is only return "undefined"

Comment: yes I tested it out...I'm using IE's debugger and can see everything it's just not pulling anything in...